# Web API call not returning

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, dotnet-httpclient

I have a RESTful Web API that is running properly as I can test it with Fiddler. I see calls going through, I see responses coming back.

I am developing a tablet application that needs to use the Web API in order to fetch data or make updates in the repository.

My calls do not return and there is not a single trace in the Fiddler to show that my calls even reach the server.

The first call I need to make is to login. The URI would be this:

http://localhost:53060/api/user

This call would normally return some information about the user (such as group membership, level of authorization and so on). The Web API uses Windows Authentication, so the repository is able to resolve all these fields based on the credentials passed in. As I said, in Fiddler I see the three calls made to the URI as the authentication is negotiated between the caller and the server. The third call returns with a JSON object that contains all information generated from the repository as expected.

Now, moving to my client I have the following:

```
var webApiClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
                                  {
                                     UseDefaultCredentials = true
                                  })
                   {
                      BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:53060/")
                   };

webApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new   MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = await webApiClient.GetAsync("api/user");
var userLoginInfo = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserLoginInformation>();
```

My call to "GetAsync" never returns and, like I said, I see no trace of it in Fiddler.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Localhost on tablet will not work, even in emulator. You need to use the machine name or IP to test it.

Comment: @Nkosi I don't think that's the cause because I've seen it working in a Jesse Liberty video on Pluralsight. He builds a Windows Store app and in the segment dedicated to Remote data, he builds a Web API that serves data to his WinStore app. He uses the tablet simulator to demonstrate the access. He accesses the Web API setting the BaseAddress to "http://localhost:33263". He does not use Windows Authentication. That would be the only difference between what I've done and what he has done. Are you saying the "localhost" won't work in Integrated Windows Authentication is used?I will give it a try

Comment: @Nkosi You may have been right after all. I configured my IIS Express to expose my Web API using the IP address and now I can see that at least one HTTP GET goes through. It generates 401. In Fiddler, once I check the "Automatically Authenticate" checkbox, there are three requests going through as the authentication is negotiated. The last one returns with the desired HTTP result 200. I have to figure out how to get my client to authenticate automatically.

Comment: What kind of tablet is it. localhost doesn't work because according to the tablet, localhost is itself. so unless the tablet is hosting the web api it would fail. The tablet is communicating with an external resource and that is why you needed to tell it to look for the server (either by name or ip). As for authentication, you may need to look at using tokens.

Comment: It's a Dell tablet but that is irrelevant because I haven't made it to the point where I side-load my app. Right now, I am just running it from Visual Studio 2013, using the simulator. Like I said, I saw an example on a Jesse Liberty course on Pluralsight (I can tell you which course and which module if you want to check it out). It worked for him with localhost. Anyway, I changed it to use the IP address and now I see the HTTP GET request hitting my server. I only need to solve the authentication issue. Thanks for your suggestion. I will mark your reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the URL where the Web API was exposed seemed to have fixed the problem. Thanks to @Nkosi for the suggestion.
For anyone stumbling onto this question and asking themselves how to change the URL of the Web API, there are two ways. If the simulator is running on the same machine with the Web API, the change has to be made in the "applicationhost.config" file for IIS Express. You can locate this file by right-clicking on the IIS Express icon in the Notification Area (the bottom right corner) and selecting show all websites. Highlight the desired Web API and it will show where the application host configuration file is located. In there, one needs to locate the following section:

```
<bindings>
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:53060:localhost" />
</bindings>
```

and replace the "localhost" name with the IP address of the machine where the Web API is running.

However, this approach will not work once you start testing your tablet app with a real device. IIS Express must be coerced into exposing the Web API to the outside world. I found an excellent node.js package that can help with that. It is called [IISExpress-proxy](https://github.com/icflorescu/iisexpress-proxy).